# React dynamic call import function from string variable

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, function-call

I want to make a function call with dynamic in ReactJS.
Summary code as below

```
import util from 'MyUtility';

export class RuiBaiComponent extends Component {

    filter(functionName) {

        // Here i want to call function in util
        eval('util.'+ functionName + '()');
        // ERROR CANNOT EXECUTED AS A FUNCTION
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
util['functionName']()
```

Comment: Great! Solved this problem under your tips.